# In symmetric group $S_n$, $g$ and $g^k$ are conjugate if $(m,k)=1$ where $m$=order of $g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Let $S_n$ the symmetric group. I'd like to show that for every $g\in S_n$, if $m$ is the order of $g$

> $g^k$ and $g$ are conjugate if $(k,m)=1$

It's well-know that $\tau, \sigma \in S_n$ are conjugate if only if they're are the same cyclic type. So let $g$ be written as products of disjoint cycles as $g:=\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_l$ where $\alpha_i$ are $k_i$-cycles. Why $$g^k:=(\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_l)^k=\beta_1 \cdots \beta_l?$$
where $\beta_i$ are $k_i$-cycles.

Comment: $n=3,k=2$ & $g=(12)$ ... doesn't work ?

Comment: I think you meant $gcd(order(g),k)=1$, in stead of $gcd(n,k)=1$?

Comment: Not, the hypotesis is $(n, k)=1$, But I had haven written the last part wrong.

Comment: The condition $\gcd(n,k)=1$ is wrong. It should be $\gcd(|g|,k)=1$. Note $|g|$ (i.e. the order of $g$) is the LCM of its cycle lengths, so $k$ is coprime to all the cycle lengths, and you can check taking a cycle to a length-coprime-power yields a cycle of equal length.

Comment: Yeah! You're are right!